# Resource not found weird issue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have working in a blog website. I have following routes

```
/categories              App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Blog\CategoryController@index  
/category/{slug}         App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Blog\CategoryController@show    
/tags                    App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Blog\TagController@index
/tag/{slug}              App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Blog\TagController@show
```

All the routes work perfectly except /tags

It shows following screen.

[image]

When I change this route to any other than `\tags` like `\tag-listing` it works perfectly
what can be the possible issue I am missing ? I can add further details if needed.

**UPDATE**

**RouteServiceProvider**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //

        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

        $this->mapBackendRoutes();

        $this->mapFrontendRoutes();
    }

    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }

    /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
             ->middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }

    /**
     * Define the "backend" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapBackendRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('backend')
            ->middleware('web','auth')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/backend.php'));
    }

    /**
     * Define the "backend" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapFrontendRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/frontend.php'));
    }
}
```

**routes/frontend.php**

```
<?php
$router->group(['namespace' => 'Frontend'], function ($router){
    require app_path('Http/Routes/Frontend/home.php');
});

$router->group(['namespace' => 'Frontend\Blog'], function ($router){
    require app_path('Http/Routes/Frontend/category.php');
    require app_path('Http/Routes/Frontend/tag.php');
    require app_path('Http/Routes/Frontend/post.php');
    require app_path('Http/Routes/Frontend/page.php');
});
```

**App/Http/Routes/tag.php**

```
<?php

$router->get('/tags', 'TagController@index')->name('frontend.tags');
$router->get('/tag/{slug}', 'TagController@show')->name('frontend.tags.show');
$router->get('/tag/{slug}/load-more-posts', 'TagController@loadMorePosts')->name('frontend.tags.load-more-posts');

$router->get('/load-more-tags', 'TagController@loadMoreTags')->name('frontend.tags.load-more');
```

**App/Http/Routes/category.php**

```
<?php

$router->get('/categories', 'CategoryController@index')->name('frontend.categories');
$router->get('/category/{slug}', 'CategoryController@show')->name('frontend.categories.show');
$router->get('/category/{slug}/load-more-posts', 'CategoryController@loadMorePosts')->name('frontend.categories.load-more-posts');

$router->get('/load-more-categories', 'CategoryController@loadMoreCategories')->name('frontend.categories.load-more');
```

I have no idea whats wrong here.

Comment: Random thought. try changin the order of the tag routes.

Comment: Post your route code

Comment: Does your .htaccess affect in any way?

Comment: @STA Do you mean controller function ?

Comment: @vivek_23 no I have not changed any other things

Comment: @KurtFriars already tried that didn't work

Comment: No, I mean your route. `/routes/web.php`

Comment: @STA I have different structure, I will add my code

Comment: If you added `/tags` later, you can just do `php artisan cache:clear` just to be sure.

Comment: @STA I have added further code

Comment: Do you see the `tags` in  output of `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: @STA Yes, it is in route list

Comment: It is clearly some weird route matching issue. If you can simply change its name and it works.

Comment: What happens if you remove the ```/tag/{slug}``` route? does it work?

Comment: What are the contents of your public folder? The presence of a /public/tags folder could cause this error.

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper I don't have such folder there